# How to access a textbox under tab panel inside jquery function?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, jquery-ui

I want to access a textbox which is inside a tab panel.

My code till now:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery.noConflict(); 
       function init() {

           jQuery('#TabContainer1_TabPanel10_txtTele').mask("(999) 999-9999"); 
       };
       jQuery(function () { init(); });  
   </script>
```

But it is not working for me.

Comment: Was the control rendered when you were trying to modify it? Posting relevant HTML/CSS code would help understand the issue better.

Comment: when I am giving alert message to find it can access the textbox or not,it is able to get the Id.But phone masking not working.@jjk_charles

Comment: Are you using a special jQuery plugin for input masks or did you intend to use the placeholder attribute?

Comment: I am using  jQuery plugin for input masks @user3558931

Comment: Which one? Did you include the plugin js to your page in addition to jQuery core?